# Team Foundation Server - What Process Template is for me?

Tags: tfs, project-management, tfs-process-template

I finally was able to complete the installation of TFS and started the creation of my first team project which introduced me to the process template.

After following to the link to [Microsoft's site](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=80608) for process template information I was inundated with new information to consider. What templates have all of you had experience with that either worked out very well for you or were more of a stumbling block to the project? What were the biggest advantages and disadvantages you've encountered?

Some information about my project, I'm the lead developer for a small company and will be using TFS/VSTS to create an intranet portal to consolidate the end users day to day and increase automation to enhance productivity etc. It's entirely new development taking advantage of C#, ASP.NET and SQL Server 2008.

Ideally I'd like to take advantage of features to enhance collaboration with the stake holders to help add desired features and to track the status of development and offer feedback etc. I was also looking to take advantage of JetBrain's TeamCity for my TFS so if any specific template / software really adds cohesion between TFS, TeamCity, Developers, and Stakeholders that would be ideally what I'm interested in.

Comment: It depends on your project. Could you elaborate some more on that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you already using a software development process like scrum? If yes you can try this Team Process Template over [here](http://scrumforteamsystem.com/en/default.aspx).

How large is your project team and the project? Microsoft has published one of it's internal Process Templates (MPT) over [here](http://mpt.codeplex.com/). You can get some guidiance and inspiration from this template.

As [tangurena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143870/team-foundation-server-what-process-template-is-for-me/1144328#1144328) mentioned. People use the standard templates, change the bug a bit and store some documents there. I would recommend to keep the process 'light' as well.

However the process template isn't all.

Here are some ideas what I would do (in your case):

- Create some high order workitems (features/stories) which stakeholdes can create (constraints and TFS user groups are your friend). They can then access their requested features via the TFS  Work Item Web Access. That way you don't need a CAL for them
- Create some reports which show planned work accodring to releases.
- Setup the build automation and create Reports (a.k.a. Release Notes) from your workitems according to the builds.

> What were the biggest advantages and disadvantages you've encountered?

Imho  the biggest disadvantage is that you start believing that the template is your silver bullet. It's not, it's your starting point. 
The TFS ecosystem offers you alot opportunities to create own bits of software that fit your needs. Just check out the [TFS API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: It was hard picking an answer for this question. Scrum for Team system seems like the way I'm going to head, another poster brought this up lower. Having 2 for scrum along with the insightful extra information you included is why i picked this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another nice [agile-based template](http://www.filefront.com/14082509/) (original is on [SSW](http://www.ssw.com.au/ssw/Download/ProdBasket.aspx?ID=AT), but you have to get around a login wall).

This template helps enhance cohesion between developers, managers, and other stakeholders by including more robust support for project process (documentation, reviews, &c., &c.).  For example, there are types built in for process elements like release plans.

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, I'd favour as small a process as you can manage.  The more states, the more fields you have, the more likely the information in them is just plain wrong.

We're running with our own version on the Agile template.  Most of what we did to it was delete stuff.

You can use the TFS API to log builds into the database, which should enable you to bridge TeamCity and TFS.  Other than that, I'd probably just go with the web interface that comes with TFS, I don't think you need third party software for this.

Answer (score 0):

K.I.S.S.!  I created a custom work item based off the Agile one.  And thats it, just one work item.  There is a "System Severity" that IT uses and a "Business Priority" that the client/customer uses.  There is also a "Request Type".  With those three along with the built in Area and Iteration the entire team, including the clients can query the work items to get only the items they care about for the release they are concerned with (or all of them regardless of the release).

I did not modify the state machine much at all.  This left us with something that is very flexible for everyone.  Everything from blue sky requests to the mundane content/visual bugs can be logged there.

The client uses TFS Web Access (unlimited CAL) and the devs (me and 1 other) use VS.  At my last job I created the same setup, the dev team was a team of 5 and it worked even better there!  I was dev lead there as well and technical PM.

**The biggest advantage was having a very flexible system for everyone, when using 1 work item type for everything.  The disadvantage would be a learning curve for the client, but once they knew how to use it most like it.  A suggestion would be to look into cheaper tools out there for a similar implementation, but, our .edu discount with MS cant be beat.**

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say that you must identify the system you will use for your company's SDLC first. The process template is merely a tool and without a good understanding of the underlying process it will not help and can make things more difficult. User adoption is crucial to the success of the SDLC and process template.

We use [Scrum for Team System](http://scrumforteamsystem.com/en/default.aspx). We chose this due to our experience with Scrum as an SDLC methodology. There are several excellent books and articles on the web to help you get up to speed. Scrum will tie together the business stakeholders into the process.

In our system the Product Manager is in total charge of Product Backlog Items and works with myself and the CTO to prioritize them into Sprint Backlog Items.

The only change we have made to the process template was to add a "Failed Test" state and corresponding workflow.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best template for you but I still wanted to mention it here: [XP for Team System](http://www.codeplex.com/XPForTeamSystem). It is basically a simplified version of MSF for Agile Software Development:

> [...] it removes some of the setup tasks that an XP project will probably not want to undertake and changes the Work Item Type name Scenario to Story.